# Find source directory from build directory in cmake

Tags: bash, scripting, cmake

I want to create a bash helper script to diff a generated file against its source. The directory structure of the output matches the source, so I should be able to find the name of the source file if I had this data:

- The name of the generated file (This will be passed to the script)
- CMAKE_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR (I need to find this out)

My plan to get this is:

- go up the directory tree searching for a CMakeCache.txt file.
- When/if found, run CMake *somehow* to print out the path to the source

How do I do that? Preferably without having to configure/generate(as that introduces a bit of delay).
Should I instead grep a specific file in the build folder? Which one?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have located the `CMakeCache.txt` you can grep for the project source dir in it in the following way:

```
cat CMakeCache.txt | grep -E '.*_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=.*' | grep -E -o '/.*'
```

This outputs the value of the [_SOURCE_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html) variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can grep for home directory in CMakeCache.txt:

`grep CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY CMakeCache.txt | cut -d = -f2-`

My cmake version:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.28.1
```